# How to group tweets and replies from pd data frame

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, jupyter-notebook

This is what our dataframe looks like [pdDataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiCkq.pngt)

It contains tweets about airlines with their replies, either from the airline or other users (or the tweetcreator himself), but each tweet or reply is a seperate entry in the DataFrame.

We want to group the replies with their corresponding tweets by extracting in_reply_to_user_id and then checking if the user_id is the same:

So far we started by inverting the DataFrame and used a for loop to iterate through it. We want to link everything togehter by checking the in_reply_to_user_id and matching the corresponding user_id. We want to continue this until we find a tweet with an in_reply_to_user_id which has value None (as we know a tweet cannot have an _in_reply_to_user_id so that would mean the end of this conversation).

[our code till now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjH76.png)

for index, row in df_kip.iterrows():

```
if (row.in_reply_to_user_id != None):
    x = df_kip.at[index, 'in_reply_to_user_id']

    for index, row in df_kip.iterrows():
        if (row.user_id == x):
            df_praten.concat([df_praten, df_kip.at[index]])
        if (row.in_reply_to_user_id == None):
            break;
```

this doesn't work however, can someone help usss? :)

Comment: Can you please add some code to the post, pictures are not a valid form of sharing code. Additionally, can please provide some sample start data and some expected results?

Comment: Put the code and data in reusable form.

Comment: for index, row in df_kip.iterrows():

    if (row.in_reply_to_user_id != None):
        x = df_kip.at[index, 'in_reply_to_user_id']

        for index, row in df_kip.iterrows():
            if (row.user_id == x):
                df_praten.concat([df_praten, df_kip.at[index]])
            if (row.in_reply_to_user_id == None):
                break;

Comment: this is the code

Comment: the exptected result are smaller dataframes that contain the tweets and their corresponding replies

Comment: @MCarre The way to update this is to update the original post not in the comments. This makes it easier to read. As well as the re-usable code to be structured in a way that a developer can copy and paste or review hard copied results.

Comment: if I understood correctly your `link everything togehter by checking the in_reply_to_user_id and matching the corresponding user_id`, you should avoid sorting the table as you have plenty empty cells in this column and... I am not sure what in this case `empty` means? New tweet maybe?
please include a bit of raw data, not all 6mils of rows, which you should not `Loop` to save the processing time, - pandas usually does not need looping. It feels like grouping should be more than enough, if the `linking` between columns would be explained a bit more precise

Comment: give a try to this line `df_grouped = df.groupby(['in_reply_to_user_id', 'user_id']).agg(tweet_text=('tweet_text' '<br>'.join)).reset_index()`